# Why am I unable to load the _tkinter module in Python when I run this script?

Tags: batch-file, python-2.7

I'm trying to make my Python program runnable for all users. I've figured out how to run Python via a Windows batch file:

```
@ECHO OFF
bin\python\python bin\main.py
PAUSE
```

But it gives me this error:

```
File "xyz/bin/python/lib/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 39,
in <module>
    import _tkinter
ImportError: No module named _tkinter
press any key to continue...
```

I have searched this on Google multiple times and it said you need to install TCL/TK. So I reinstalled Python (making sure I included TCL/TK) and it still didn't work. It doesn't have that error if I am using python on its own.

Comment: Could you give us the structure of your python program if you're still having this issue? I suspect that you don't have python set up properly and that it is looking to import that module from the wrong place.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding python libs\ path to your "PATH" variable.
e.g. `set PATH=c:\Python27\libs`
It looks like you have installed python in some nested folders, and running the bat file which is depending on where it is located.
Maybe your PATH environment variable is outdated
Also, you can try with `PYTHONPATH`